# Как правильно использовать Clipboard?

Tags: c#

Код :

```
SendKeys.Send("%{TAB}");
Clipboard.SetText(fromTextBox.Text);
SendKeys.Send("^v");
for (int i = 0; i < 12313; i++)
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}");
Clipboard.SetText(toTextBox1.Text);
SendKeys.Send("^v");
```

В результате вставляется два раза второй текст. В чём ошибка ?

Upd:

```
fromTextBox.Text = "В лесу родилась елочка";
toTextBox1.Text = "Росла она там";
```

Приведенный выше код вставит в поле другой программы:

Росла она там*КучаТабуляций*Росла она там

Мне нужно:

В лесу родилась елочка*КучаТабуляций*Росла она там

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите более полный пример кода. И что за **второй** текст вставляется? Какой результат Вы ожидаете, какой получаете?

Comment: Как должно быть: в буфер копируется сначала один тест, затем вставляется. После этого копируется второй текст, затем так же вставляется. Но, приведенный выше код вставляет два раза тест из toTextBox1.Text

Comment: Не отвечайте в комментариях. Лучше обновить Ваш вопрос. Лучше всего с примерами текста, который Вы вставляете, копируете.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно будет использовать такой код:

```
[DllImport("USER32.DLL")]
public static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
Process[] handles = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
SetForegroundWindow(handles[0].MainWindowHandle);
Clipboard.SetText(text);
SendKeys.SendWait("^v");
```

Вставляет как положено